# Why h.response return a string instead of object on HapiJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, hapi

I am creating an **API** with HapiJS, using TDD I am receiving an error because the test validates the payload of the request, curiously, I receive a string instead of an object as the documentation says.

This is my test written with @hapi/lab:

```
it('payload should be a json object', async () => {
    const res = await server.inject({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/users'
    })
    console.log(res)
    expect(res.payload).to.be.object()
  })
```

and this is my route:

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/users',
  handler: (request, h) => {
    const data = {
      message: 'App'
    }

    const response = h
      .response(data)
      .type('application/json')
      .header('content-type', 'application/json')
      .code(200)
    
    return response
  }
})
```

By the way, that console.log in the test is to confirm the content of the res.payload and verify that it was receiving a string instead of an object.

This is the specific error I get from the test:
`Expected '{"message":"App"}' to be an object but got 'string'`

Comment: According to the documentation it is a string: _"payload - the __response__ payload string."_. Maybe you were looking at the definition of `payload` for the `inject()` options which is _"payload - (optional) an string, buffer or object containing the __request__ payload"_

Comment: You're right. So if inject can contain a string, buffer, or object, how can I set an object with the HapiJS route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `result` on the `response` object you get from `inject` method.

`payload` is the data from the endpoint as `hapi` would send to the client, meaning it was serialized. That's the reason you get a string. Instead the `result` property is the raw data returned from the endpoint before serialization. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://hapi.dev/api?v=20.2.0#server.inject()) in the `return` section.

Here is a code snippet to showcase this:

```
const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");

const server = Hapi.Server();

server.route({
  method: "GET",
  path: "/test",
  options: {
    handler(req, h) {
      return { result: 1 };
    },
  },
});

(async function () {
  await server.start();

  console.log("server started");

  const res = await server.inject({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/test",
  });

  console.log(res.payload); // ==> '{"result": 1}'
  console.log(res.result); // ==> { result: 1 }
})();
```

Also to answer one of the comment you made, you actually already sent an object from your `hapi` server. It's just that the data was serialized. You'd need to deserialize it in whatever context you'd be calling your endpoint, with `JSON.parse()` for example, before you could use it.